# Self-hosted Gitlab with SSL certificate not accesible through HTTPS

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, gitlab

I'm trying to install and configure Gitlab on a ubuntu server making it accessible from external network by a subdomain that directly points to the public IP (fixed) of the server.

At the moment I've been able to set up the Gitlab and properly configure the DNS of my subdomain making a "A" register which points to the public IP of the server, and seems to be working fine since I can access the server from external network via HTTP.

The problem begins when I try to configure Gitlab to run via HTTPS with the SSL certificate; I generated the certificate using Letsencrypt and set up aswell the Nginx configuration for Gitlab in order to run via HTTPS (/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb)

Apparently the certificate seems to be properly generated since I've already checked it with the openssl verify command pointing both ~/chain.pem and ~/cert.pem files. The verification returns an OK.

My external_url parameter is set to HTTPS and I've also set the Nginx parameters as they sould be:

```
nginx['enable'] = true
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.mydomain.com/privkey.pem"
nginx['ssl_dhparam'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/dhparams.pem"
nginx['listen_port'] = 80
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

<sub>I've written mydomain.com to avoid sharing the actual domain but in the configuration it has the proper value</sub>

When I try to access the subdomain via HTTPS the connection is refused while if I try to access via HTTP it works fine.

My Nginx configuration file after doing a gitlab reconfigure looks like this:

```
server {
  listen *:80;


  server_name gitlab.mydomain.com; 
  server_tokens off;
  client_max_body_size 0;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

  add_header Referrer-Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin;

  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log gitlab_access;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  if ($http_host = "") {
    set $http_host_with_default "gitlab.mydomain.com:443";
  }

  if ($http_host != "") {
    set $http_host_with_default $http_host;
  }

  gzip on;
  gzip_static on;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_min_length 10240;
  gzip_proxied no-cache no-store private expired auth;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/json;

  proxy_read_timeout      3600;
  proxy_connect_timeout   300;
  proxy_redirect          off;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;

  proxy_set_header Host $http_host_with_default;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;

  location ~ (.git/git-receive-pack$|.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack$|.git/gitlab-lfs/objects|.git/info/lfs/objects/batch$) {
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
  }

  location /-/grafana/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }

  location /-/grafana/avatar {
    deny all;
    return 404;
  }


  include /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-health.conf;

  location / {
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_pass  http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }

  location /assets {
    proxy_cache gitlab;
    proxy_pass  http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 /500.html;
  error_page 502 /502.html;
  location ~ ^/(404|500|502)(-custom)?\.html$ {
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
    internal;
  } 
}
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: You only have `listen *:80;` for accepting HTTP. Where is your `listen *:443 ssl;` for accepting HTTPS?

Comment: I've changed the ```listen *:80;``` to ```listen *:443 ssl;``` and restarted Gitlab but still only can access via HTTP (HTTPS remains refused)

Comment: @MarcHernández did you manage to find the solution to your issue?